# How can I get the sender ID of dynamically created submit buttons?

Tags: php, html

I'm generating a html table. Each row starts with a Edit-Button.

***Site A:***

```
echo "<table border='1' align='center'>";
    echo "<tr>"
      . "<th style='font-weight:bold'></th>"
      . "<th>".$nr.":</th>"
      . "<th>Anschrift</th><th>Nachname</th>"
      . "<th>Vorname</th>"
      . " <th>PLZ</th>"
      . "<th>Ort</th>"
      . "</tr>";
    echo "<form action='lxKundenEdit.php' method='POST'>";
    $i=0;
    foreach($arr as $key =>$value)
    {                  
        echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='btn'.$i.'\'' value='Bearbeiten'/></td>";
        foreach($value as $subkey=>$subValue)
        {
            echo "<td>".$subValue."</td>";
        }            
        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</table>";
```

Then I want to know which button has been pushed. When vardump the POST-Array it seems nothing really works. Any hints about this? regards, Ismir

***Site B:***

```
var_dump($_POST['btn0']); //f.e.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is:

Make array of all your submit buttons with ids as keys.

```
echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="btn[<?php echo $i;?>]" value="Bearbeiten"/></td>';
```

And then in PHP, get posted submit buttons like:

```
if (! empty($_POST['btn']) {
  foreach ($_POST['btn'] as $btnId => $btnVal) {
    // $btnId is Id of the button that is $i
    // $btnId means button is pressed.
    // $btnVal is value of the button
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an error that $_POST['btn'] is empty (null)

Comment: ok,my fault, forget a closing bracket, I var_dumped this now and got this: rray (size=1)
  '<?php echo 0;?>' => string 'Bearbeiten' (length=10) , ok this helps me I think, thk u =)

Answer (score 3):

Simply pass the sender ID in a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="sender" value="<?= $senderID; ?>">
```

On Site B you can then get the value from the `$_POST` variable:

```
echo $_POST['sender'];
```

#### Edit

I see I misread your question. What you can do is pass your subkey on the submit button as follows:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit[<?= $subkey; ?>]" value="send" />
```

Comment: got to try this, one moment pls

Comment: this doesnt work for me, 1st error is 'undefined variable $sender

Answer (score 3):

You should give each button a unique value. When the form is posted you can then check for that value for that button.

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="btn'.$i.'" value="'.$i.'" />';
```

**Edit:**

As Peter pointed out in the comments, if you want to change the text of your button, you can use the button element:

```
<?php

echo '<form method="post">';
echo '<button type="submit" value="button 1 was used" name="button">Send</button>';
echo '<button type="submit" value="button 2 was used" name="button">Send</button>';
echo '</form>';

var_dump( $_POST[ 'button' ] );
```

Comment: You'll want the submit button to say 'Sned form' or something like that instead of an id.

Comment: @Peter I updated my answer to use the button element instead of an input. This element won't show the value as the text of your button and thus it's possible to set your text as something else.

Answer (score 1):

Just include a hidden input inside your form, eg

```
<input type='hidden' name='submit'/>
```

So you can use it to check, if the form has been sent (if(isset($_POST['submit'])) etc). Then check any other $_POST fields looking for any ['btn...'], eg

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ // check all the $_POST fields
   if(substr($key,0,3) == 'btn'){ // if its name begins with 'btn'...
      $button_id = substr($key,3,NULL); // then that's some button. Get its ID
   }
}
```

Think this should work